# Adding/changing properties in all the tags of a type (odd results)

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to add/change some properties in all tags of a certain type after the page is loaded.

I found two ways. But for some reason that I don't understand, the results are different.

Method 1 - adding a style tag as the last child of <html>.

```
var style = document.createElement( "style" );

style.innerHTML = `

div {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

`;

document.documentElement.appendChild( style );
```

[Result of style tag as last HTML child method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xWjf.jpg)

Method 2 - Getting all the tags of that type and painfully having it change them one.

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("div");

for( let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ){

  elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
  elems[i].style.color = "white";

}
```

[Result of loop/in-line method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSplM.jpg)

So I was wondering why the results between the two methods are different, and I'm also happy to learn about other methods of changing all tags of a type of course.

Comment: It might be the priority at which CSS engine is applying the style. Inline styles overwrites css styles.

Comment: @vanowm I see, I assumed that since styles was added at the very end, it would take priority. And I have seen in-line properties/attributes be ignored too, what can overrule in-line's priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference was priority. The same inline results of method 2 (loop/inline), were achieved with method 1 (`<style>` as last child) by adding the `!important` rule due to the increased priority. Like so:

```
div {
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

Simple example demoing how to easily and fully revert all changes, and be left back with the original HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

  p {
    background-color: red;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

  <p>Text sample.</p>

  <p style="background-color: grey">Text sample.</p>

  <button onclick="test1()">Remove temporary changes</button>

</body>
<script>

  function test1() {
    document.getElementById("tempChanges").remove();
  }

</script>
<style id="tempChanges">

  p {
    background-color: green !important;
  }

</style>
</html>
```

Comment: While `!important` works, it's unadvised because it's harder to overwrite if you need to, for example on a specific page or inline for a certain element

Comment: @CanO'Spam Thanks. Yea I understand this, but for my use-case it needs to have the highest priority and is  only kept in effect temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

- the first method it creates a `<style>` tag and sets its attributes like you would write the css in the `<style>` tag or enter it via `<link>`
- the 2nd method uses the `style` attribute of each tag which is also W3C standard but scoped to just that tag and has syntactic limitations (cannot use selectors like `:hover` , `:focus`...)

the 2nd method is faster than 1 and has higher precedence and no error about `scoped` it is preferred in javascript

Comment: Really? The second method (loop/inline) is faster? I would have thought that manually changing them one by one would have been way less efficient than a styles tag which are specifically meant for affecting many tags of a type.

Comment: you may think so because javascript looks heavy but actually creating the style tag makes the browser do more than it has to interact with the DOM (it's expensive) traverse all the indexes looking for selectors and finally the same is implementing the css response

Comment: I was as confused as you were until I ran the performance tests. method using `class` is almost equivalent to `style` and they are both faster than `<style>`

Comment: if you need to change from 2 or more properties you might want to use `class` it's easy and fast to write

Comment: Hmm, great tip, thanks. And that holds true regardless of how many tags are at play (e.g. 300+)?

Comment: Class wouldn't be an option for my purpose I think, as it wouldn't be my HTML. So I'd need to first create a style element as in method 1, to add the class properties, and then add a class to every tag of a type. Or are you saying that this is also faster?

Comment: if you can't insert `<style>` as soon as the page loads then `style` will be faster than `class`. to your question `style` will be faster than `<style>` even with 300+ elements i tested with my site of about 2000 elements

Comment: just that `class` looks cleaner. you can also refer to `.cssText` it will write more neatly than `style` for an almost equivalent cost

Comment: I wouldn't be able to change anything until the page is fully loaded, no. Damn, I am incredibly surprised that it's faster even with such large amounts of elements, definitely super useful to know, thanks. Neatness of the active HTML is not an issue, so that's fine. And I'd like to use .cssText, but I can't use it as I don't want to remove any other previously set style property in these elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Method 1 adding a new style tag to the document and applying CSS styles using the `innerHTML`. All tags on the page that match with the selector `div` will have the styles using this technique. However, depending on how much styling is required, this technique may result in a slower page load.

Then,another method which is selecting the background and color properties of each div element on the page by looping through all of them. This approach is quicker because it doesn't need to wait for new styles to load.

So, another method you can use just by changing a bit in your second method is:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for( let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++ ){
  elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
  elems[i].style.color = "white";
}
```

Nevertheless, you can also use Jquery for shortcut execution :

```
$("div").css({
  "background-color": "black",
  "color": "white"
});
```

Comment: changing `style` property of element is the same as changing style attribute.